# Eliminate records using a JOIN instead of NOT IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

This query works as I would expect it to, but I am trying to avoid using the "not in":

```
select * from subscribers ls join emailopens eo
    on ls.subscriberid=eo.subscriberid
    where ls.listid=1381 
    and opentime  > 1458864000
    and emailaddress not IN (select emailaddress from subscribers where listid=1384)
```

I have tried this:

```
select * from subscribers ls join emailopens eo
    on ls.subscriberid=eo.subscriberid left join subscribers ls2
    on ls.emailaddress=ls2.emailaddress
    where ls.listid=1381 
    and opentime  > 1458864000
    and ls2.listid=1384
```

The problem is that it only returns the rows that have the same email in both `listid=1381` and `listid=1384`. I thought since I am using a left join it should return ALL rows `where listid=1381`, and then on rows where the same email is in `1384`, would have the data, but if there is an email in `1381` and not `1384`, would show `null` from the `ls2.*` columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `ls2.listid` in the `WHERE` effectively turns your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Try keeping the `listid` constraint in the `ON`, and then, to produce the effect of a `NOT IN`, make this an anti-join by asking for records where `ls2.emailaddress IS NULL`:

```
select * from subscribers ls join emailopens eo
    on ls.subscriberid=eo.subscriberid left join subscribers ls2
    on ls.emailaddress=ls2.emailaddress and ls2.listid = 1384
    where ls.listid=1381 
    and opentime  > 1458864000
    and ls2.emailaddress is null
```